# Does Gaze Interaction work for UWP app on HoloLens 2 using its inbuilt eye tracker

Tags: uwp, hololens, windows-community-toolkit

I'm trying to get gaze interaction to work for buttons in my UWP application on HoloLens 2. The MS Dynamics Guides example does work.

I've tried the simple application described below and ran that - no luck.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/gaze-interactions

I've downloaded the community toolkit below and ran that - no luck.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/gaze/gazeinteractionlibrary

The eye tracker privacy options have been manually set to allow for the apps, the ask for permissions box is not appearing automatically. The toolkit has a "Please attach eye tracking device" error message.

[Gaze Error from Community Toolkit Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH6G9.png)

I must be missing something obvious - any help appreciated.

Cheers

Mark

Comment: Were you able to implement this successfully in your UWP application?

Answer (score 1):

What we want to point out is that you should use the [SpatialPointerPose API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Input.Spatial.SpatialPointerPose?view=winrt-19041) to access head and eye-gaze rays on the HoloLens2. For more detailed information about how to access eye tracking data, please refer to our developer guides for [using eye-gaze in DirectX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/native/gaze-in-directx)

Besides, OpenXR is another way Windows Mixed Reality supports to do that, you can start developing OpenXR applications for HoloLens 2 with this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/native/openxr-getting-started). And Microsoft provided the [EyeGazeInteractionUwp Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenXR-MixedReality/tree/master/samples/EyeGazeInteractionUwp) shows the usage of [XR_EXT_eye_gaze_interaction](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenXR/specs/1.0/html/xrspec.html#XR_EXT_eye_gaze_interaction) extension.

Comment: We have an UWP application but need to add the gaze feature, it will be good if there are any suggestion to include gaze with out going for C++ code. Are there any alternative option to enable through C# code.